# React and Redis keyspace notifications

Tags: reactjs, redis

I'm trying to create the following system:
A **React client side** which responds to **data updates** (by a server side), on a **local machine**.

Instead of using periodic HTTP calls to the server, of using web-sockets and listening to the server, I was thinking about setting up a local Redis key-value repository, and listening to changes there (data is written by the server side) using [Redis keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications).

As someone really new to Redis, is that a reasonable use case for Redis?
If so, how do I do that using [Node-Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) (didn't see any reference to keyspace notifications there)?

Answer (score 2):

React really isn't my jam but on the surface, this looks reasonable to me. I can answer the keyspace notifications question with authority, however.

Keyspace notifications use the same mechanism as PubSub. So, to make use of these from Node Redis, you need to use the `.subscribe` or the `.pSubscribe` method. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#pubsub) but here's the tl;dr.

Subscribing will block your connection. So, you'll almost always want to duplicate it:

```js
const subscriber = client.duplicate()
await subscriber.connect()
```

Once you have a connections, just call `.subscribe` to monitor a particular event or `.pSubscribe` to watch a pattern that matches potential events. I find I usually use a pattern. The below code should match any keyspace or keyevent:

```js
await subscriber.pSubscribe('__key*__:*', (message, channel) => {
  console.log(message, channel)
})
```

Also, keyspace notifications are not enabled by default. So, you'll need to enable them. You can do this in redis.conf or from redis-cli:

```
CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEA
```

Hope this helps!